# Flash Player not working on IE 10

Tags: windows-8, internet-explorer-10, flash-player, windows-8-x64

I'm using Windows 8 and my problem is Internet Explorer can not open pages of content over the flash player.
I've tried some things, but still could not find any solution on the web.
Can you help me on this?
Thank you ...

Comment: Are we talking about 32-bit Windows or 64-bit Windows?

Comment: windows 8 x64-bit.

Comment: You have installed the 32-bit and 64-bit verison of Flash right?

Comment: Flash is embedded in IE for Windows 8. See http://forums.adobe.com/message/4814662.

Comment: Yes Flash is embedded in IE for this i cant reinstall or uninstall this.Still same problem.How can i fix this ?